# How to create a custom transformer from Elastic result to Doctrine entity

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

## tl;dr

How to extend / override the base transformer from Elastic result to Doctrine entity in FosElasticaBundle?

## Details

I'd like to change the `transform` method in `FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\AbstractElasticaToModelTransformer` so that I can add a custom property to the retrieved entities.

I tested by hacking that method, and it works exactly as I want.

What's the best solution to override / extend that method without hacking it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the transformer and define your own by creating a new service. The full story can be read at http://obtao.com/blog/2014/05/advanced-indexing-with-elasticsearch-foselasticabundle/

Shortly: first you define a service like this (in my case I only index one specific entity):

```
myapp.elastica_to_model.transformer.company:
    class: AppBundle\Transformers\ElasticaToCompanyTransformer
    arguments: [ @doctrine, "AppBundle\Entity\Company" ]
    calls:
        - [ setPropertyAccessor, ["@fos_elastica.property_accessor"] ]
    tags:
        - { name: fos_elastica.elastica_to_model_transformer.app.company }
```

Then you create the actual service class, where you extend the original transformer and override the `transform` method.

Finally you tell FosElastica to use this transformer instead of the original one:

```
fos_elastica:
    indexes:
        app:
            types:
                company:
                    mappings:
                        ...
                    persistence:
                        ...
                        elastica_to_model_transformer:
                            service: myapp.elastica_to_model.transformer.company
```